# Table is showing up too low

Tags: tables, beamer, minipage

it is my first time asking a question here. I am making a beamer presentation and in some moment I had to use minipage two break my page in two. The first minipage is a table with points and the second an image ( a cartesian plane so student can identify the points of the table on the cartesian plane).
However my table keep showing up really low. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example 2}
Complete the table  of values below. Then plot the points on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.20\linewidth}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
\hline
$x$&$y=x^2+1$\\
\hline
$-1$&\textbf{0}\\
\hline
$0$&\textbf{1}\\
\hline
$1$&\textbf{2}\\
\hline
$2$&\textbf{5}\\
\hline
$3$&\textbf{10}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Unit4W1L6-image2.png}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome @SebaMath! Off-Topic: I like the 0 in the first row if x = 1 ;).

Comment: Yeah I saw that mistake. Nice one that you catch that ;) I was clearly working modulo 2 on that line :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've simplified the code (mainly by reducing the number of `minipage` environments). The `array` and the graph are now centered vertically next to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example 2}
Complete the table  of values below. Then plot the points on the Cartesian plane.

\bigskip
%\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more "open" look
$\begin{array}{|r|c|} % use 'array' rather than 'tabular' since contents are 'math-y'
\hline
x&y=x^2+1\\
\hline
-1&\mathbf{0}\\ % use '\mathbf', not '\textbf'
\hline
0&\mathbf{1}\\
\hline
1&\mathbf{2}\\
\hline
2&\mathbf{5}\\
\hline
3&\mathbf{10}\\
\hline
\end{array}$
%\end{minipage}%
\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Unit4W1L6-image2.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much this help me a lot. Can I ask you why my original code wasn't working as desire? I though that minipage makes a minipage and if I try to make a table on that "new page" it will make it on the top since it has [t]. Sorry I ask :)

Comment: @SebaMath - What did it, mostly, was eliminatgin the "outer" `minipage` and omitting the `[b]` positioning specifiers for the two "inner" `minipage`s. Once this main adjustment was made, keeping the `minipage` "wrapper" turned out to be inessential for the `tabular`/`array` environment, but essential for the graph. (Getting rid of the `flushleft` environment is ok because the graph occupies the full width of the `minipage`, The positioning of `minipage`s relative to one another depends not only on their own positioning specifiers (`[c]` by default) but also on what's inside them.

Answer (score 4):

Beamer has `column`s for that purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example 2}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{8cm}
Complete the table  of values below. Then plot the points on the Cartesian plane.
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.30\linewidth}
%\begin{table} %<- do you need that?
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
\hline
$x$&$y=x^2+1$\\
\hline
$-1$&\textbf{0}\\
\hline
$0$&\textbf{1}\\
\hline
$1$&\textbf{2}\\
\hline
$2$&\textbf{5}\\
\hline
$3$&\textbf{10}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{table}
\end{column}
%\hfill
\begin{column}{0.7\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```